# Mapping 3D data on a unit sphere

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a three D data set and I am trying to map it on the surface of a unit sphere. I don't know how to start but I found some papers in web but it is not clear to me how to use them. Can you share you thoughts on this algorithm.

In my data I have three value at each point. For example a coffee mug. I have the exact coordinates of each point on the mug surface. Now I want to map mug on a unit sphere. Any help in this regard.

I also found a similar post here in stackExchange at [Messed up Sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105173/messed-up-sphere)  but they are using opengl. I want to use this in simple plane c or fortran code.

Thank you.

Comment: On which plane do you want to project you data?

Comment: To simplify the problem, let me explain it here. Let us assume that I have 3D random numbers between (-10,-5,-10) to (20,10,30). This is a three D grid. I know all the points which are at the outer surface of this grid. So problem is : How to map all those outer points on the surface of a unit sphere.

Comment: So you don't want to just project them to a plane, you want to transform them into corresponding points inside a unit sphere, don't you? If I've understood you, do you have a equation for the sphere or not? I mean are you limited to a particular sphere or not?

Comment: Yes you are right. I just want to map all points(x,y,z) which are outside in my problem,  to the  surface of a unit sphere. I as search web and found this problem is similar to environmental mapping or 3D descriptors.

Comment: Can't you just normalize your point?

Comment: Similar to this problem, a question was asked here at stackoverflow. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209142/map-on-a-unit-sphere-with-polar-coordinates

Comment: Do you think normalization in a unit circle is similar to map data on unit circle.